# Tarefa do gulp não roda (mas vira callback)

Tags: gulp

Tenho uma tarefa no gulp, definida mais ou menos assim:

```
gulp.task('tarefa', ['a', 'b', 'c'], function () {
   console.log("tarefa executada com sucesso");
});
```

Pelo que eu entendi da [documentação](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn), esse código deveria fazer o seguinte:

- Definir a tarefa de nome *"tarefa"*;
- Executar em paralelo as tarefas *"a"*, *"b"* e *"c"*;
- Após o término das tarefas *"a"*, *"b"* e *"c"*, executar a lógica definida para a tarefa.

O que ocorre realmente:

- É definida a tarefa de nome *tarefa*;
- As tarefas *"a"*, *"b"* e *"c"* são executadas em paralelo;
- O programa para, indicando sucesso, mas a lógica que eu defini para a tarefa *tarefa* não é executada.

No entanto, notei que se nas demais tarefas eu receber um parâmetro, e tratar esse parâmetro como função... Como por exemplo:

```
gulp.task('a', function (callback) {
    callback();
});
```

O `callback` acima é a função que eu defini como corpo da tarefa *tarefa*.

Eu gostaria de rodar a minha tarefa somente após as demais terem rodado, e como elas vão rodar em paralelo, não posso usar minha função como callback das demais tarefas.

O que eu devo fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos indicar em uma tarefa qual é sua dependência, isto é, qual tarefa deve ser executada antes.

veja esse exemplo que a tarefa copy aguarda a tarefa clean terminar de execultar:

```
// adicionando clean como dependência da tarefa copy

//na tarefa copy passo ['clean']

gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

//na tarefa clean passo return
gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return gulp.src('dist')
        .pipe(clean());   
});
```

Veja que as tarefas são executadas uma por vez, porque nesse contexto não faz sentido que sejam executadas em paralelo